# Dynamic action to update database record AND redirect to a different page

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I'm building a system of modal dialogs to allow users to edit database records.

1. The user clicks the "Edit" button on a specific row in a report somewhere
2. A modal dialog pops up, with fields that the user can edit and manipulate
3. The dialog has four standard buttons the user can select: `Cancel`, `Delete`, `Save`, and `Create`

Let's start with the `Save` button.

By default for modal dialogs, the `Save` button has the following behavior:

[image]

I presume this **1)** submits the information from the items in the modal dialog (which refreshes the browser, closing the modal dialog), and then **2)** performs the SQL `UPDATE` action with the submitted information, in time for the refreshed page to include the updated information?

This is fine, but I need to:

1. Avoid refreshing the browser (e.g. submit individual items, rather than the whole page), and
2. Manually redirect to another modal dialog (a different page) *AFTER* the SQL `UPDATE` action is completed

I presume this can be accomplished with dynamic actions, but I don't know how.
How can I ensure the database action is completed, before the dynamic action which navigates to a new page?

Comment: What version of APEX are you using?

Answer (score 0):

> Manually redirect to another modal dialog (a different page) AFTER the SQL UPDATE action is completed

I'm thinking of creating a **branch** with Server-side condition set to "When button pressed" (for every button), or perhaps "Request is contained in value" where request name (by default) equals button name.

So: button would first do its *processing* part, and then *branch* to another page, without involving dynamic actions.